Github Copilot Error - "Unable to resolve model with family selection: gpt-4" in Github Copilot
I was getting error in Github copilot, without making any changes
"Unable to resolve model with family selection: gpt-4"


To fix it , try adding this settings in VSCode
"github.copilot.advanced": {
        "debug.useNodeFetcher": true,
        "debug.useElectronFetcher": true
    }
} 

Restart the editor after updating this setting.
